# Implementing one-hot encoding using r

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

For the dataset I am working on there is a lot of character variables that I want to one-hot encode them in order to build some predictive models. In my code I am excluding two variables because it does not make sense to encode them, they are the item identifier and establishment year of the store. Here is the code I am using:

```
one_hot_encoding = dummyVars("~.", data = train[,- 
c("Item_Identifier", "Outlet_Establishment_Year")], fullRank = T)
ohe_df = data.table(predict(one_hot_encoding, train[,- 
c("Item_Identifier", "Outlet_Establishment_Year")]))
train = cbind(train[,"Item_Identifier"], ohe_df)
```

When executing the first line it gives this error:

> Error in -c("Item_Identifier", "Outlet_Establishment_Year") : 
>     invalid argument to unary operator.

Why? and one question regarding the `dummyVars` function: does it by default exclude the numeric variables of the input dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it excludes by default the numeric variables.

Concerncing your error, there are some workarounds:

1. With the `dplyr`-package

   `select(train, -Item_Identifier, -Outlet_Establishment_Year)`
2. And with base-R

   `train[, -which(names(train) %in% c("Item_Identifier", "Outlet_Establishment_Year")]`

   OR just use the number of the column like

   `train[, -c(1,6)]`

Comment: No, the rest of the dummyVars() function stays exactly the same.